# How do I copy non-adjacent columns to another excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm needing to copy multiple non-adjacent columns to another excel workbook named Extract.xlsx

```
'Path to destination
MyPath = "C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\Template\Extract.xlsx"

'Range Selection 
Range("A:A, G:G, J:J, K:K, M:M").Select 'This is what I initially recorded from excel macro, but realised that an error popped up saying "That command cannot be used on multiple selections."

'Open Destination Workbook, was testing it out separately so I know this part onwards works
Workbooks.Open(MyPath)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath)
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws1.Activate
Range("A1").Select
Activesheet.Paste
```

I've attempted to look for some examples but I either didn't quite get what they were saying or the same error message popped up

Comment: I you get an error, you should at least tell us what error and which lines throws it

Comment: @FunThomas I did include the error and where it pops out, but you have to scroll >>>> as I think it's a bit long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use PasteSpecial, you can copy your data in one row. I'll just add variables for readability and usability:

```
dim Rng_A as Range, Rng_B as Range, wb as Workbook, ws1 as Worksheet
MyPath = "C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\Template\Extract.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open(MyPath)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath)
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' ThisWorkbook - for a book where code is executed
set Rng_A = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Your_Sheet_Name").Range("A:A, G:G, J:J, K:K, M:M")
set Rng_B = ws1.Range("A1")
Rng_A.Copy Rng_B
```

Since you are working with several sheets/workbooks I advise you to be aware of the field of view for your code and try to avoid Range(...) usage without the object it's related to.

Comment: thank you! I'm not sure what you mean, but have put the codes accordingly, `Rng_A` before launching `ws1` but it prompts `Method or data member not found` where the `.Range` part in `Rng_A` is at

Comment: OMG forget that! It works! I just needed to make it `Rng_A = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Range("A:A, G:G, J:J, K:K, M:M")` Thank you so much!

Comment: Probably you mean something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`?

Comment: Sorry, missed Worksheet part for Rng_A. Edited with a random name - you can fill with yours. I'm glad it helped.